# How to get method name from Action in WinRT

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-runtime, expression

I'm trying to get the method name from an Action in WinRT, where Action.Method is not available.  So far I have this:

```
public class Test2
{
    public static Action<int> TestDelegate { get; set; }

    private static string GetMethodName(Expression<Action<int>> e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("e.Body.NodeType is {0}", e.Body.NodeType);
        MethodCallExpression mce = e.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (mce != null)
        {
            return mce.Method.Name;
        }
        return "ERROR";
    }

    public static void PrintInt(int x)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("int {0}", x);
    }

    public static void TestGetMethodName()
    {
        TestDelegate = PrintInt;
        Debug.WriteLine("PrintInt method name is {0}", GetMethodName(x => PrintInt(x)));
        Debug.WriteLine("TestDelegate method name is {0}", GetMethodName(x => TestDelegate(x)));
    }
}
```

When I call TestGetMethodName() I get this output:

```
e.Body.NodeType is Call
PrintInt method name is PrintInt
e.Body.NodeType is Invoke
TestDelegate method name is ERROR
```

The goal is to get the name of the method that is assigned to TestDelegate.  The "GetMethodName(x => PrintInt(x))" call is only there to prove that I'm doing it at least partly right.  How can I get it to tell me that "TestDelegate method name is PrintInt"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is much simpler than I was making it.  It's simply TestDelegate.GetMethodInfo().Name.  No need for my GetMethodName function.  I wasn't "using System.Reflection" and so Delegate.GetMethodInfo wasn't appearing in intellisense, and I somehow missed it in the docs.  Thanks to HappyNomad for bridging the gap.

The working code is:

```
public class Test2
{
    public static Action<int> TestDelegate { get; set; }

    public static void PrintInt(int x)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("int {0}", x);
    }

    public static void TestGetMethodName()
    {
        TestDelegate = PrintInt;
        Debug.WriteLine("TestDelegate method name is {0}", TestDelegate.GetMethodInfo().Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static string GetMethodName( Expression<Action<int>> e )
{
    Debug.WriteLine( "e.Body.NodeType is {0}", e.Body.NodeType );
    MethodCallExpression mce = e.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if ( mce != null ) {
        return mce.Method.Name;
    }

    InvocationExpression ie = e.Body as InvocationExpression;
    if ( ie != null ) {
        var me = ie.Expression as MemberExpression;
        if ( me != null ) {
            var prop = me.Member as PropertyInfo;
            if ( prop != null ) {
                var v = prop.GetValue( null ) as Delegate;
                return v.Method.Name;
            }
        }
    }
    return "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Delegate.Method does not exist in WinRT.  But in the process of playing with your code, I found Delegate.GetMethodInfo() which is all I needed in the first place.