# Delegate.Method property on WinRT

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, windows-runtime

I'm trying to port a Unity game to WinRT and currently have a problem with delegates. The current code uses the Method property of the Delegate class. But this property seems not to exists on WinRT anymore. What is the alternative for this on WinRT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment on a similar question:

> Thanks, but Delegate.Method does not exist in WinRT. But in the
>   process of playing with your code, I found Delegate.GetMethodInfo()
>   which is all I needed in the first place.

Perhaps that `Delegate.GetMethodInfo()` will be what you are looking for.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648026/how-to-get-method-name-from-action-in-winrt) is the original question, for anyone interested in additional details.

Comment: Getting the error that System.Delegate does not contain a definition for GetMethodInfo

Comment: You will need to add `using System.Reflection;`

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Be sure to upvote and/or accept my answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: Ah, forgot about that limitation.  I think you may have at least 15 now :)